# Toggle state after n clicks in t seconds

Tags: android, rx-java

I want to use RxJava to toggle a menu on and off if the user clicks n times on a button within a t seconds window. After t seconds have lapsed the click counter should reset and the cycle starts over.

I have a solution in place see below:

```
    RxView
            .clicks(view.findViewById(R.id.title))
            .map(new Func1<Void, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(Void aVoid) {
                    return 1;
                }
            })
            .publish(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<List<Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<Integer>> call(final Observable<Integer> sourceObservable) {
                    return sourceObservable.buffer(sourceObservable, new Func1<Integer, Observable<Long>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<Long> call(Integer aVoid) {
                            // we trigger after 2 seconds, or after MIN_CLICKS_TOGGLE clicks have been recorded
                            return Observable
                                    .merge(Observable.timer(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                                            sourceObservable.buffer(MIN_CLICKS_TOGGLE_MODE - 1)
                                                    .map(new Func1<List<Integer>, Long>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public Long call(List<Integer> integers) {
                                                            return 1L;
                                                        }
                                                    }))
                                    .first();
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .filter(new Func1<List<Integer>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(List<Integer> integerList) {
                    return integerList.size() == MIN_CLICKS_TOGGLE_MODE;
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Integer> integerList) {
                    toggleMode();
                }
            });
```

However this solutions has 2 problems:

- the closing observable (a merge of a timer and a buffer to count the clicks) only works if I subtract 1 from the number of clicks I want to detect
- if I click n + 1 times, the toggle function is called twice, so the menu opens and closes

Any suggestions on how to improve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`window` with boundary provider](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#window(rx.Observable)) operator, this way windows will be created only after the first click.

```
    final int MARK = 0;
    final int TRIGGER = 1;

    final BehaviorSubject<Integer> boundaryObservable = BehaviorSubject.create();

    RxView.clicks(view.findViewById(R.id.title))
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Void ignore) {
                    // Checks if window is open and in proper state(MARK) 
                    if (boundaryObservable.hasValue() && boundaryObservable.getValue() == MARK) {
                        boundaryObservable.onNext(TRIGGER);
                    }
                }
            })
            .window(boundaryObservable.filter(new Func1<Integer, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Integer value) {
                    // Only use TRIGGER values as window boundary values
                    return value == TRIGGER;
                }
            }))
            .flatMap(new Func1<Observable<Void>, Observable<Notification<Void>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Notification<Void>> call(Observable<Void> longObservable) {
                    return longObservable
                            .skip(CLICK_THRESHOLD-1)
                            .take(1)
                            .timeout(WINDOW_SIZE, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            // materialize is needed to pass information about 
                            //ending of the window but to not close the obserable 
                            //with an error if it timeouts
                            .materialize();
                }
            })
            .filter(new Func1<Notification<Void>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Notification<Void> booleanNotification) {
                    return booleanNotification.isOnNext() || booleanNotification.isOnError();
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Notification<Void>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Notification<Void> notification) {
                    Log.d("TTAG", "Got " + (notification.isOnNext() ? "good clicks" : "timeout") + ". ");
                    // Save information that new window is ready to be opened on next click
                    boundaryObservable.onNext(MARK);
                }
            })
            // filter only onNext events to prevent premature ending of the observable
            .filter(new Func1<Notification<Void>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Notification<Void> booleanNotification) {
                    return booleanNotification.isOnNext();
                }
            })
            .dematerialize()
            .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object o) {
                    Log.d("TTAG", "Finally got the click. ");
                }
            });
```

---

**Previous attempts:**

You might use a [buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) operator
So your code would look like:

```
RxView.clicks(view.findViewById(R.id.title))
  .buffer(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)     
  .map { clickList -> clickList.size }
  .filter{ size -> size > CLICK_THRESHOLD}
  .subscribe { /*Your sucessfull "toggle" clicks*/ }
```

What will happen is `buffer` will "split" source observable for fragments of `WIDNOW_SIZE` seconds and then map resulting `clickList`s to their size and then filter those `size`s to be bigger than `CLICK_THRESHOLD`.

The example is written in Kotlin but is directly translatable to Java.

---

Other take is to use [window](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html) operator which also allows you to split observable to pieces but emissions from those pieces are available immediately.

```
RxView.clicks(view.findViewById(R.id.title))
        .window(WINDOW_SIZE, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Observable<Long>, Observable<Long>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Long> call(Observable<Long> longObservable) {
                return longObservable
                        .skip(CLICK_THRESHOLD)
                        .take(1);
            }
        })
```

Skip and take operators allow you to signal only once that the threshold was reached.

---

Comment: Thanks, but I already went down this path. This waits for the buffer to fill before issuing an observable, while I would like to trigger as soon as n clicks are in, without having to wait for the end of the time window. Also if you have some clicks left over in the buffer from an earlier interaction the count would be off.

Comment: I have added an alternative version with window instead of buffer - did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The problem with window is that it keeps spitting results at a constant window interval. If my click threshold is 5 and I click 3 times before and 2 times after a window boundary it does not work, the results are 3 and 2 as opposed to 5 as expected. However, it may be possible to achieve what I want with the window version that takes an opening and a closing selector, I need to look into this.

Comment: I just tried the solution with `window` on a button in an Android view and it works just fine. Did you by any chance used a sort of "wating" operator, that is one that waits for the observable to complete before releasing you the result: `count`, `toList()`, etc. ?

Comment: Window doesn't work because the window starts every t seconds, not when the first click comes in. As indicated above, some clicks fall in one window and some fall on the next, so although I click n times it does not trigger because none of the windows have n clicks, they're spread across 2 windows. You have to be lucky to start the first click at the beginning of a window so all fall within the same window.

Comment: I have added yet another take on your problem, see the answer.

Comment: Awesome, that does it. Thanks so much for your perseverance, this is some advanced stuff here, I'll spend some time digesting it. I tried earlier the window with opening/closing, but it would not work for (n + 1) or more clicks as I was getting multiple windows, all with n clicks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached a similar problem, but I required only 2 clicks so it needed a little modification. Due to this, code is not tested.

```
RxView.clicks(view.findViewById(R.id.title))
            .map(aVoid -> new Date().getTime())
            .buffer(n, 1) // every time upstream emits, it forwards last `n` emissions in a list to the downstream 
            .filter(aTimestamps -> (aTimestamps.get(aTimestamps.size() - 1) - aTimestamps.get(0)) < TIMEOUT)
            .throttleFirst(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Note that using `throttleFirst` operator for filtering out the multiple clicks is ***not*** bullet-proof until the timeout set for it is more or equal than TIMEOUT const value. But it might not matter anyways, if you just want to get rid of accidental over-clicking.